# Implement toggle short-cuts in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

Let me preface my problem by thanking your for your help and for forgiving me potential short-comings in my first post.

**Description**
I want to use my keyboard shortcuts in excel to quickly format spread-sheets. Since I for example often use the same 4 font colors, I wanted to create a toggle short cut (e.g., Shift + Ctrl+ K = Blue font, Press K again, Green font, Press K again red font, Press it again, return to original font color).

**Current Approach**
I managed to assign the relevant Macro once I hit Shift + Ctrl + K

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.OnKey "+^b", "ShortcutsFormatFontColor" End Sub
```

**Problem**
I struggle to find a solution how I can call another Macro / alter the Macro if I press Shift + Ctrl + K again --> If I want to toggle through various design cases with the same shortcut.

Thank you!

Comment: Not tested but you could use an `If...Then` or `Select Case` statement evaluating the current font colour and e.g. if it's `Green` then change font colour to `Red`. etc.

Comment: You may like to look at this code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582649/how-to-cycle-through-borders-in-excel-and-change-their-color/60583600#60583600. There the border color changes but the code could easily be modified to change the font color instead.

Comment: Have an array of values you want to cycle through, and increment an index at each invoke (and back at 0 if it reaches the `UBound`)

Comment: Thank you! Circling through cases / arrays works well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be ... in Workbook_Open assign to the macro key.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnKey "+^k", "ShortcutsFormatFontColor"
End Sub
```

Create a code module and add the ShortcutsFormatFontColor routine which cycles through the colors. In this particular example, the code changes the color of all selected cells, but uses the cell in the top-left of the selection to determine the reference color:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ShortcutsFormatFontColor()

    Dim vSelection As Range
    Dim vNewColor As Long

    Set vSelection = Application.Selection

    If vSelection.Cells.Count > 0 Then
        Select Case vSelection.Cells(1, 1).Font.Color
        Case rgbBlue: vNewColor = rgbGreen
        Case rgbGreen: vNewColor = rgbRed
        Case rgbRed: vNewColor = rgbBlue
        Case Else: vNewColor = rgbGreen
        End Select
        vSelection.Font.Color = vNewColor
    End If

End Sub
```